# What does of(true) method do in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, typescript

I was reading from [angular official site](https://angular.io/guide/router#canactivate-requiring-authentication).
What does **of(true)** method mean and why it is used?

```
login(): Observable<boolean> {
    return of(true).pipe(
      delay(1000),
      tap(val => this.isLoggedIn = true)
    );
  }
```

Comment: `of(true)` creates a new observable that emits the value `true`

Comment: Using `of()` we can return a fake response without creating any real backend connection. Here it's using true to set the `isLoggedIn` status for the user.The only thing that `of()` does is that it emits its parameters as single emissions immediately on subscription and then sends the `complete` notification.

Answer (score 1):

`of(true)` creates a new observable that emits the value `true`. Your complete code above simulates a timeout of 1 second before setting `isLoggedIn` to `true`.

You could also rewrite that using [`timer`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/timer.html) instead (add `map` only if you care that `true` was returned).

```
return timer(1000).pipe(tap(val => this.isLoggedIn = true), map(() => true));
```

Comment: uh? why should he rewrite that?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo - `could != should`